# Extend Laravel Router

Tags: php, laravel, router

I implemented a role/permission system. Now I want to add a method to Laravel router so I can make something like this:

```
Route::get('sales', 'SaleController@index')->allow('Salesman');
```

I know that I can use `@can('Salesman')` **(View)** and `$user->can('Salesman')` **(Controller)** but I found so much readable the way I'm trying to do it since I'll be able to see all role permission access in the routes file.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the router class, then register it into service container to be used by `Route` facade.

To be more clear:

- Write a class that extends Laravel's router (I think `Router` class). To find this, open the `Route` facade, then find its service provider. From there, it should be easy to find the router class.
- Write a class that overwrites that router. Make sure to extend the class you found before.
- Write a service provider that overwrites the router services. The practically means to register your service under the same key name you find in `Route` facade.

And that should be it. Your service is now picked by `Route` facade automatically.

Comment: I'm getting this Exception after doing all you said: Declaration of App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot(App\Router $router) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Routing\Router $router)

Comment: You maybe are extending your provider from Laravel. This is not necessary, and may cause problems like that one. Just read what Laravel does in that provider (`RouteServiceProvider`), and make yours just like that. But replace the `Router` with your own.

Comment: I'm not extending the provider. I'm extending laravel router.

Comment: But the error says otherwise, `Declaration of App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot(App\Router $router) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Ro‌​uting\Router $router)` which means `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` is extending `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` and their `boot` methods' signature are not the same

Answer (score 0):

As you're using the facade to generate the routes. This should be quite easy. The facade can be overruled in the `config/app.php` [`facades`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L199) array.

You can generate your own [Facade class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades) and replace the native one with yours. Which in fact is a [Router class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php). In order to implement the functionality you need to extend and override the following in sequence:

- Facade
- Router::newRoute
- [Route](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php)

By extending the last one and returning those in the `newRoute` method of the Router, you'll be able to overrule the logic of Laravel.